# How to change nuxt-link-exact-active style depending on the route

Tags: css, nuxt.js, nuxt-link

```
a.nuxt-link-exact-active::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: var(--secondary);
  transition: width .3s;
}
```

This works as intended. However I wish to change the background to another color depending on the route I'm visiting via NuxtLink.